# Why am I getting a parse error for the input?

Tags: haskell

```
import Data.List
import System.IO

 list = [logBase a b | a <- [1,2..], b <-[1,2..],a<100,b<100]
 inv x = 1/x
 print inv (list)
```

Above is my code block. And my terminal says

> error: parse error on input `list'.

I've tried adding a main function there, but the terminal gave me an error (indentation was correct). When I independently typed those in the terminal it did not give me any errors, though the list gave me a strange value. How can I print out the list formed by inverting all elements of the list `list`?

Comment: the strange value will be because a list is not a number, and doesn't have an inverse (what would be `1/[1,2,3]`?) - do you want the list of inverses of all the values in the original list, instead? that would be `print $ fmap inv list`

Comment: also, if you want to run a `print` function, it needs to either be in GHCI or in an IO function called by `main`, and the indentation on `list = […]` here is causing an error

Comment: Now I get it, thank you! But could you explain why you used $ in front of fmap?

Comment: it's the same as `print (fmap inv list)` - context: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-36- (and a bit of quick advice: if you're not sure what a function is, it's usually possible to find it on hoogle! eg, https://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=(%24) )

Comment: (hoogle is one of my favourite haskell resource in existence, it's so useful! i still use it to look up basic stuff all the time, just because it's nice to be able to double check im not misremembering something)

Comment: @janet If you remove your comments and post them as an answer then Pauline Yoo can accept your answer. StackOverflow works best with answers instead of comments.

Answer (score 0):

The indentation error is because `list` etc are indented. Also, in order to run, `print` should be used in an IO function called by `main`, or used in GHCI.

The strange value is because lists are not numbers, and `1/[1,2,3]` will not return a sensible value. If you want the list of inverses of the values in the original list, that would be `print $ fmap inv list`.

`($)` is an operator to make function application easier - this expression is equivalent to `print (fmap inv list)`. An incredibly useful resource for finding information like this is Hoogle, eg https://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=(%24). Hoogle will return this context for `($)`: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-36-

Here's some example code, with two versions for working inside of or outside of `main`:

```
list :: [Double]
list = [ logBase a b | a <- [1,2..], b <-[1,2..], a<100, b<100 ]

inv :: Double -> Double
inv x = 1/x

main :: IO ()
main = do
    print $ fmap inv list
```

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
    let list = [ logBase a b | a <- [1,2..], b <-[1,2..], a<100, b<100 ] :: [Double]
    let inv x = 1/x
    print $ fmap inv list
```

`list` and `inv` could be defined in `main`, or at top level like in my example code - if at top level it will be possible to reuse these functions outside of `main`, if in `main` it will be possible to reuse their names elsewhere.